# Do you know the Mellin transform of $e^{-\lfloor x\rfloor}$, where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the floor function?

Tags: proof-verification, convergence-divergence, mellin-transform

After I did calculations to get the Mellin transform $$\mathcal{M}  \left\{ e^{-\lfloor x\rfloor} \right\}(s), $$ where with  $\lfloor x\rfloor$ we are denoting the floor function I asked me about if my result was right, and where converges the function.

After that I've combined the definition of Mellin transform and floor function, my result was $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k^{s-1}}{e^k},$$ and Wolfram Alpha said to me that it is $\Phi(\frac{1}{e},1-s,0)$, that is a particular value of a [Lerch Transcendent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html).

> **Question.** Can you verify if my result was right? If the result is right only is required a *yes* here. What is the domain of convergence for my example? How compute the domain of convergence? **Many thanks.**

---

I tried also repetead the exercise with the fractional part function $\operatorname{frac}(x)=\{x\}$ instead of the floor function, but it is more difficult. Do you know if it was in the literature?

Comment: Shouldn't the Mellin transform be $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(k+1)^s - k^s}{s e^k}$? It seems like you forgot to integrate the $x^{s-1}$ part.

Comment: Now I read the answer from the user, but as you see then I had a mistake, many thanks for your answer also from your comment @user399601

Comment: My mistake was that I did the substitution with $k$ also in the $x$ !!!!! Many thanks @user399601

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\text{Re}(s) > 0$ (so the integral converges at $0$)
$$\eqalign{{\mathcal M}\left\{e^{-\lfloor x \rfloor}\right\}(s) &= \int_0^\infty 
e^{-\lfloor x \rfloor} x^{s-1}\; dx \cr
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_k^{k+1} e^{-k} x^{s-1}\; dx \cr
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-k} \frac{(k+1)^{s}-k^s}{s}\cr}$$
The series converges absolutely, so we can rearrange:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty  (e^{1-k}-e^{-k}) \frac{k^s}{s} = \frac{e-1}{s} \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-k} k^s$$

If you replace $\lfloor x \rfloor$ by $\left\{ x\right\}$, it never converges:
$e^{-1} \le e^{-\left\{ x\right\}} \le 1$, and you need $\text{Re}(s) > 0$ for convergence at $0$ but $\text{Re}(s) < 0$ for convergence at $\infty$.

Comment: Many thanks now I am going to study your nice answer.

Comment: I see now the mistake that said  user399601. I did the substitution $k$ also in the $x^{s-1}$. Many thanks also for your calculation for the convergence.